# How to display images in a loop in HTML

Tags: html, django, for-loop

In a loop I iterate over several URLs stored in movie.poster. If I only print movie.poster it returns the URL.

```html
<ul>
    {% for movie in all_movies %}
        <li> {{ <img src="movie.poster" alt="Cheetah!" /> }} </li>
            <!--<input type = "submit" value = "delete"/>-->

            <!-- <img src="movie.poster" alt="Cheetah!" />-->
    {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

When I run the code below I get the following error message "Could not parse the remainder: […]" How could I fix this?

Comment: Please add relevant tags

Comment: Please add some more info, like what template engine you are using and other frameworks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use `{{ }}` for variables not for a line, and `.url` to call an image

so:

```html
<li><img src="{{movie.poster.url}}" alt="Cheetah!"></li>
```

will call the image